# Injective Function satisfying all certain domain

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies $f(f(x)) − f(x) = x$. Is f injective? Why? Find all values of x such that $f(f(x)) = 0$.

I think the function is one to one, though I am somewhat scratching my head to figure out why. I rearranged and got the following: $x + f(x) = f(f(x))$, this makes the composite a function of the actual $x$ and original function. That means for every $x$, there must be some $y$.

This is my intuitive thinking, but is not accurate likely.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) = f(y)$, you have

$$f(f(x))-x = f(f(y))-y$$

It imply that

$$f(f(x))-x = f(f(x))-y$$

i.e

$$x = y$$

Hence f is injective.

For the second question, you have

$$f(f(0))-f(0) = 0 $$

So you get $f(f(0)) = f(0)$, but as $f$ is injective, $f(0) = 0$. but because f is injective, it's the only value that verify $f(x) = 0$